# Unable to push to a transferred repository: "The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, github, repository

I transferred ownership of a repository to an organization in which I have ownership rights. However, now I cannot push to the repository. I get this error:

```
$ git push origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What are the steps that I need to take in order to be able to push to do pushes again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you adjusted your remotes to reflect where the repo now is?

`git remote -v`

Will show all remotes with their URLS, and

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:[organisation]/[repo].git`

Is the syntax to update it if they are out of date.

Answer (score 2):

[According to this page](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-different-access-permissions), Admins do not appear to automatically get access to the org's repositories.  Try adding the repo to a team you are a member of.

Comment: I just checked, it looks like I am an "owner" instead of an admin. So I did already have rights to the repository. I edited the question to say "owner" instead of "admin".